# Gradient opacity on the bottom of div

Tags: html, css, gradient, opacity

I would like to create effect like on this image - gradient opacity on the bottom of content:
[image: opacity]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this HTML

```
<div class="content">
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simply dummy text<br>


     <div class="gradientback">

     </div>
</div>
```

With This CSS

```
body{background:#000;}
.content{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.gradientback{

    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(137,255,241,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(137,255,241,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(137,255,241,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(137,255,241,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(137,255,241,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(137,255,241,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0089fff1', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/ndfUs/)

Comment: 2 errors in the above code. Extra `</div>` in the HTML and 'position' spelled incorrectly in the `.content` css rule.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to exist anymore. Would it be possible to update that link somehow?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is older but JIC someone finds this looking for a solution. The accepted answer from Love Trivedi is good but still has a few problems. Using absolute positioning is ok but to cover the div; it's suggested to also use top: 0px and right: 0px. there are also extra zeros in the `filter`, the start should be `startColorstr='#89fff1'` to stay consistant with the other starting colors.

There are also 2 downsides to this solution. First it doesn't allow for selecting the underlying text so you would need a `pointer-events: none;` in the gradientback class to allow selecting the text. The second problem is this solution fades to a color so you have to be sure your second color matches the page background to get the desired effect. This uses an overlay DIV so fading that to transparent wouldn't do anything to the visual of the content DIV.

here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ygw6L2h/1/) with the suggested changes and a link on the first text line so you can test the pointer-events option.

.

A more modern solution would be to use the CSS3 mask-image. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmfd4sya/) example for solution 2.

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(black), to(transparent));
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, transparent 100%);
mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(black), to(transparent));
mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, transparent 100%);
```

it has less support for older browsers but actually fades the container to transparent allowing for any variety of page backgrounds while still maintaining the desired effect.

.

here is updated HTML for the first solution in case jsfiddle gives you problems

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>gradient test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="gradient test">
    <meta name="author" content="Viking">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<style>
body {
    background: #000;
}
.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gradientback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))); /* Chrome, Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10+, Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#89fff1', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
}
</style>

<div class="content">
    Loriem <a href="https://google.com" target="google">ispsum</a> is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    <div class="gradientback"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the modern solution. You don't need the inner DIV, just add the `mask-image` lines to the content class.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>gradient test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="gradient test">
    <meta name="author" content="Viking">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<style>
body {
    background: #000;
}
.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(black), to(transparent));
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, transparent 100%);
    mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(black), to(transparent));
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, transparent 100%);
}
</style>

<div class="content">
    Loriem <a href="https://google.com" target="google">ispsum</a> is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
    Loriem ispsum is simpaly dummy text<br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope you want some thing like [this](http://www.sanbeiji.com/archives/1002).

```
div {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.8)), to(rgba(80,80,80,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#333333));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a image and set it fixed on the bottom.
[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-trick-fade-out-the-bottom-of-pages-with-a-fixed-position-image/) have a post about this issue and deliver also the picture.

Or if you want it with CSS, follow [this](http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/) article which shows you how to do this with CSS and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will solve your problem. White and black gradient

```
.box{
    padding: 15px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(221, 221, 221,0.8)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255,0.2)), color-stop(.5,#fff));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have an repeating image. For example a 10px height gradient.

position your div to relative :

```
/* Example width*/    
    div {
        position : relative;
        width    : 500px;
    }
```

Your image would be position absolute

```
#gradientImage {
    height     : 10px;
    background : url(path/to/image.png) repeat x;
    position   : absolute;
    bottom     : 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

> Your div also has to have a width so your repeating image will depend on the width of the parent

Comment: I would use `position: fixed` to stick it to the bottom of the page.